# Storing dynamic data client side vs server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, indexeddb

Say on the frontend I have a dashboard with a set of user inputs and a paginated data table that renders based off of those inputs. Upon applying new filters or manually refreshing data, a request is sent to pull data from backend database. However, if the user chooses another page on the data table, no request should be sent to get data from the backend database because that data is constantly updating. In other words, only new data should be shown when new filters are applied or user explicitly refreshes NOT when clicking through different table pages.

So, wondering if using client side storage liked indexed db for the most recent request makes sense here and then paginating from client side storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want separate pages to be based on the data as of the latest filter or refresh, then unless you want to have vast quantities of versioned data on the back-end, paginating on the client side sounds like the way to go.

Depending on the size of your data, Indexed DB could be a great option for performance, but if you aren't expecting large amounts of data, then simply storing the response in state might be the simpler solution.

Comment: Data will be pretty large, potentially 10s of thousands of objects

Comment: I would think that either state or IndexedDB could work for you. It's always good practice to ask if you need to send every row to the user, as well. So maybe they can locally page through 1000 results, and to view more, they would have to refresh the data from the back-end. Then state is the easy, performant option that doesn't cost unnecessary DB reads for you or harm UX for those on poor connections. IndexedDB [best practices](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/indexeddb-best-practices) may even include keeping a copy in state anyway.